# Python: Add JPG images to popup in folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to add jpg images to marker popups on a map using folium. So far I have a program that will scan a folder of images and plot their location on a map in chronological order. I have read some of the other threads on here and I have attempted to implement the code however those deal with singular images and not a folder of them.

I need to be able preview all the jpg images in the folder on each marker on the map.

When i run the code i am met with this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IMG_0097.jpg'

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

````
import os, exif, folium, base64

def convert_lat(coordinates, ref):
    latCoords = coordinates[0] + coordinates[1] / 60 + coordinates[2] / 3600
    if ref == 'W' or ref == 'S':
        latCoords = -latCoords
    return latCoords
filename=[]
coordList=[]
map = folium.Map(location=[51.50197125069916, -0.14000860301423912], zoom_start = 16)

from exif import Image
with os.scandir('gps/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:   
        filename= [i.name for i in entries if not i.name.startswith('.')]
        sortedList = sorted(filename, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]))
        for c in range(len(sortedList)):
            img_path = ('gps/'+sortedList[c])           
            with open (img_path, 'rb') as src:
                img = Image(src)            
                if img.has_exif:
                    latCoords = (convert_lat(img.gps_latitude, img.gps_latitude_ref))
                    longCoords = (convert_lat(img.gps_longitude, img.gps_longitude_ref))
                    coord = [latCoords, longCoords]
                    coordList.append(coord)
                else:
                    print (src.name,'has no EXIF information')

count=0
for c in range(len(coordList)):
    popmsg = "Count is "+str(count+1)
    if count==0:
        fileimg=(sortedList[c])
        encoded = base64.b64encode(open(sortedList[c], 'rb').read())
        html= '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{}">'.format
        resolution, width, height = 75, 50, 25
        iframe = IFrame(html(encoded), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20)
        popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=1000)
        folium.Marker(coordList[c],popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(icon='home',prefix='glyphicon')).add_to(map)
    elif count==(len(coordList)-1):
        folium.Marker(coordList[c],popup=popmsg,icon=folium.Icon(icon='flag',prefix='glyphicon')).add_to(map)
    else:
        folium.Marker(coordList[c],popup=popmsg,icon=folium.Icon(icon='asterisk',prefix='glyphicon')).add_to(map)
    count+= 1
        
        


folium.PolyLine(coordList, color =" red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(map)```
````

Comment: I can't verify this because I don't have a free image with image information, but I think you need to create multiple popups for the target folder using local variables or something. If you are already able to display the images, no problem, but I think you need to use .decode(). `encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read()).decode()` This information was referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227034/png-image-not-being-displayed-on-folium-map).

Comment: I tried this but it gives a different error as the user in this thread was using a PNG whereas im using JPGs

Comment: Were you able to create a popup object with the images in the directory of the other assignment, and IMG_0097.jpg is not the last image file?

Comment: In the previous comment, the code is `for c in range(len(coordList)): ... vars()[f'popup_{c}']=folium.Popup(...) Popup(...) ;folium.Marker(...) , popup=[f'popup_{c}'],...)` This represents the fact that